# What is the mark placed on Cain?

Tags: exegesis, genesis

> "And the Lord put a mark on Cain, lest any who found him should attack him." Genesis 4:15 ESV

What is the mark placed on Cain?

Comment: I think it was just a "kick me" sign.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to have been a mark of warning, not of protection, to those who may think to harm him. The mark was a sign of God's mercy for this murderer. Unfortunately, others warped the meaning of the sign and applied it to themselves later in the same chapter:

**Genesis 4:23-24**

> Lamech said to his wives: “Adah and Zillah, hear my voice; you wives
>   of Lamech, listen to what I say: I have killed a man for wounding me,
>   a young man for striking me.   If Cain’s revenge is sevenfold, then
>   Lamech’s is seventy-sevenfold.”

Mankind misconstrued God's mark of mercy to be a mark of license, and had no problem killing others who bothered them. To them it was a mark of "revenge" not mercy. Thus, mankind grew worse and worse, since there was no fear of God in them. So the Flood was necessary, and after the Flood, came God's clear command so we would not make the same mistake:

**Genesis 9:6**

> “Whoever sheds the blood of man, by man shall his blood be shed, for
>   God made man in his own image.

They did not seem to see the mark as a physical mark; it appears that they just applied it to themselves as a matter of principle: "I killed a man, so I am marked by God, too."

Answer (score 1):

The Bible doesn't say what the mark was. I think the verse you quote is all that we're told about it. It is puzzling. I always picture some symbol on his forehead, like a tatoo. But nothing in the text spells that out.

The whole point is that people who knew Cain was a murderer might take it upon themselves to execute him. But that would require that they recognize him and know what he did. So if God had commanded that Cain not be killed, why would an additional mark be necessary? And if it was some sort of symbol, how would anyone know what it means? Or was it words, like "Don't dare kill this man, signed, God"?

A teacher years ago suggested that maybe it wasn't anything like a symbol or tatoo at all, but rather, a look in his eyes. It sounds to me like that could make a great ending to a story. "And then he turned and looked at me, and I knew I couldn't kill him. I dropped my weapon. For suddenly I knew who he was. That haunting, hunted, hated look in his eyes. He bore the mark of Cain." I'd write that story except I can't think of anything interesting to go before that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Cain  and  Abel  reprsent  the  two  classes  of  people  at  the  end  of  time.  Cain  represents  the  wicked,  and  Able  represents  the  righteous.

1  John 3;12  Not  as  Cain,  who  was  of  the  wicked  one,  and  slew  his  brother.  And  wherefore  slew  he  him?  Because  his  own  works  were  evil, and  his  brother's  righteous.
Matthew 13;19  When anyone  heareth  the  word  of  the  kingdom,  and  understandeth  it  not,  then  cometh  the  wicked  one,  and  catheth  away  that  which  was  sown  in  his  heart.  This  is  he  which   received  seed  by  the  way  side. 
1 John 3;8  He  that  committeth  sin  is  of  the  devil;  for  the  devil  sinneth  from  the  beginning.  For  this  purpose  the  Son  of  God  was  manifested,  that  he  might  destroy  the  works  of  the  devil.

Exodus  33;16,17  For  wherein  shall  it  be  known  here  that,  I  and  thy  people  found  grace  in  thy  sight?  is  it  not  in  that   thou  goest  with  us?  so  shall  we  be  seperated,  I  and  thy  people,  from  all  the  people  that  are  upon  the  face  of  the  earth. And  the  LORD  said  unto  Moses,  I  will  do  this  thing,  also  that  thou  has  spoken:  for  thou  has  found  grace  in  my  sight,  and  I  know  thee  by  name.

Isaiah 13;9,11  Behold,  the  day  of  the  LORD  cometh,  cruel  both  with  wrath  and  fierce  anger,  to  lay  the  land  desolate:  and  he  shall destroy  the  sinners  thereof  out  of  it.  And  I  will punish  the  world  for  their  evil,  and  the  wicked  for  their  iniquity;  and  I  will  cause  the  arrogancy  of  the  proud  to  cease,  and  will  lay  low  the  haughtiness  of  the  terrible.

Revelation  22;11  He  that  is  unjust,  let  him  be  unjust  still: and  he  which  is  filthy,  let  him  be  filthy  still:  and  he  that  is  righteous,  let  him  be  righteous  still: and  he  that  is  holy,  let  him  be  holy  still.

Answer (score -1):

The only people who survived the flood were Noah, his wife, their 3 sons and their wives, 8 people (Genesis 7:13, 1 Peter 3:20).  None of them were descendants of Cain, so the mark of Cain has died out, whatever it was.  (Some believe it was the Neanderthals.)   Many people, however, confuse the mark of Cain with the curse of Canaan in Genesis 9:25 "Cursed be Canaan; a servant of servants shall he be unto his brethren."  That's a completely different thing.  The descendants of Canaan were the Canaanites, as you read in Genesis 10, and also the cities of Sodom and Gomorrah were populated by them.  So the curse of Canaan sets up the story for the destruction of Sodom and Gomorrah as well as the Israelite conquest of the land of Canaan.

Comment: "The mark of Cain has died out." I don't know anything in the Bible that says that the mark was genetic, that it was something that Cain would pass on to his children. I've always assumed it "died out" when Cain died.